# Actual minimum bounding geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a dataset of many (>13 million) points, representing borders of potential quick clay zones, and need to enclose them *exactly* by polygons. Each cluster has an ID, however, the tools "minimum bounding geometry (convex hull)" and "concave hull" yield larger areas than the minimum which would enclose the points. Is there a more precise way to get the minimum bounding area?

(Basically, I want the red areas removed)

[image: example]

Comment: Check this https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-alpha-shapes

Comment: @Taras the problem is, they are (and need to be) grouped by ID, I didn't find a way to group them with alpha, or did I overlook something?

Comment: You are correct, there is not grouping field in the "Concave hull (alpha shapes)" tool. You can either: (1) Collect geometries by `"ID"` and apply the Concave hull with iterating over each feature or (2) Split features by `"ID"` then apply the Concave hull and after merge the outputs from the previous step

Comment: @Taras thanks for the tip! Splitting features isn't really an option for me, since I've got some 10'000 areas, but I'll try collect geometries -> concave hull/alpha

Comment: @BERA same cluster, I tried coloring them different, but that was too much for the PC^^